# Properly close TCP server when using cluster

Tags: node.js

I have below sample code where I am forking child processes, starting a TCP server and closing the server after certain timeout. When I looked at TCP connections after timeout, I still see that one connection is in listening state.

Also there are no client connections on this server and I see that server's 'close' event is also firing for each worker.

Strangely the server accepts new connections also. How to close the TCP server completely in cluster environment?

I am using node 0.10.31 version.

```
var net = require('net');

var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Fork workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {

    var server = net.createServer(function(sock) {
        console.log('received connection...');
    });

    server.on('listening', function() {
        console.log('listening....');
        setTimeout(function() {
            server.close();
        }, 5000);
    });

    server.on('close', function() {
        console.log('server closed');
    });

    server.listen('2222', '101.30.33.194');
}
```

on running lsof after timeout to check tcp connections:

```
#lsof -ni -P | grep 2222
node      17228    root   14u  IPv4 440505953      0t0  TCP 101.30.33.194:2222 (LISTEN)
```